# Programmatically Created NSTableView throwing Failed to marshal the Objective-C object (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, monomac, xamarin.mac

In my Xamarin Mac project, I have set up a NSTableView programmatically. I have a custom NSTableHeaderCell that I am using for the column header cells. For some reason on some machines, it's throwing an error

```
Failed to marshal the Objective-C object 0x121f77e90 (type: XXXTableHeaderCell). Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance (because the type 'XXXTableHeaderCell' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument).
```

I know this can be thrown if you're loading from a nib/xib, but I'm building it all in code.  I also know it can happen if your managed object gets GC'd, but the header cell and column objects should be held on to by the table view.

Putting in an empty constructor that takes an IntPtr seems to fix the issue, but I'm concerned that it's creating a new object when it should be using something that already exists (or should still, at least).

Am I missing something in how these are held?

Comment: Without seeing any code it is tough to help, but yes, almost always that error is due to an ObjC obj that lives without its managed counterpart (that got GC'd). I would make sure that your XXXTableHeaderCell has a class level reference somewhere.

Comment: To rule that out, I did add class-level objects for each column and header cell in my NSTableView subclass.  I'm still trying to figure out who's even calling the IntPtr constructor.  It's being called twice, but I have four columns.  I would expect it to be called 4x or none... but two?  Unfortunately, I can't post the code itself.  I'd try to whip up a sample, but it would take more time than I can spare, and it only happens on some machines.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of the error likely contains the key:

'XXXTableHeaderCell' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument

Did you expose a constructor that takes an IntPtr (that calls base with that pointer)? That is used in marshaling between managed and native code.

Comment: I did end up adding one. But all of the columns and headers are manually allocated in my code. The crash wasn't until later. I'm not sure what else would have been trying to marshal them.